# Taking two lists as input that contain words, to form a tuple with two words, one from each list that have the same starting letter of each word

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I've to take two lists as an input which contain words. Using those words I form a tuple using two words, one from each list that contain the same first letter of each word. Then creating a list of those tuples and printing them.

I have a solution, however, I cannot seem to produce the same item twice. Here's an example of what I mean in words.

List A: `['Jack', 'Tim', 'John', 'Ahmed']`

List B: `['Julie', 'Tom', 'Henry', 'Harper']`

```
c = input().lower()
d = input().lower()

a = c.split()
b = d.split()

x = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i][0] == b[i][0]:
        x.append((a[i], b[i]))

print(x)
```

My Output: `[('joy', 'juggle'), ('troy', 'trim')]`

Expected Output: `[('Jack', 'Julie'), ('John', 'Julie'), ('Tim', 'Tom')]`

I'm quite new to learning the language and wasn't quite able to find any similarities to my previous work to find out how I could reiterate through a / b without reproducing the same output.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
There is no way your posted code could produce the output you claim, as those words do not appear in the input lists.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.product` to get all the pairs and then filter them out:

```
In [1]: from itertools import product

In [2]: a =  ['Jack', 'Tim', 'John', 'Ahmed']

In [3]: b = ['Julie', 'Tom', 'Henry', 'Harper']

In [4]: out = [i for i in product(a, b) if i[0][0] == i[1][0]]

In [5]: out
Out[5]: [('Jack', 'Julie'), ('Tim', 'Tom'), ('John', 'Julie')]
```

Comment: Okay, thank you, however, rather than using itertools would you know of any possible way of completing it without that? Rather quite basic code, as the tutorials I have been following recommend I don't use them until further on into it. If not I hopefully can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehensions:

```
In [50]: a = ['Jack', 'Tim', 'John', 'Ahmed']

In [51]: b = ['Julie', 'Tom', 'Henry', 'Harper']

In [55]: c = [(x,y) for x in a for y in b if x.lower()[0]==y.lower()[0]]

In [56]: c
Out[56]: [('Jack', 'Julie'), ('Tim', 'Tom'), ('John', 'Julie')]
```

Comment: Yes that works, thank you very much, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
[(x, y) for x in A for y in B if x[0] == y[0]]
```

Comment: Thank you, amanb demonstrated that in his answer, cheers for the input though.